# Powershell Write-Host versus Write-Output and newlines between list items

Tags: powershell, scripting

I can write output from Powershell with the following script:

```
Write-Host "Hello", "1234"
Write-Output "Hello", "2345"
```

The output from this program is:

```
Hello 1234
Hello
2345
```

So, the Write-Host with a comma separated list puts a space between the items.  The Write-Output puts a newline between them.  There are lots of differences between the 5 different Write-xxxxxxx statements, but **why in the world would the output differ between these 2 statements and how can change Write-Output to act like Write-Host?**

WTF Microsoft?

Comment: `Write-Host` breaks the pipeline so you shouldn't use it to process data. It writes directly to the console.

Comment: I can recommend the following blog post, which discusses `Write-Host` and mentions some alternatives: http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

`Write-Output` understands objects and it writes to the pipeline, while `Write-Host` doesn't since its role is to write to the console host. You generally shouldn't use `Write-Host` except in special cases because that way you loose object oriented interface of Powerhsell and revert to cmd.exe paradigm.

To get what you want use:

```
write-output "$('Hello', '2345')"
```

When you put array inside of the string it is joined and delimited with `$OFS` separator which is by default `<space>`.

To understand this more clearly, consider the following example:

```
> write-output "hello", "world" | % { "item" }
item
item
> write-host "hello", "world" | % { "item" }
hello world
```